# How do I change an image from a column when I hover over a table row that was added via a button function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, web

How do I change an image from a column when I hover over a table row that was added via a button function?

The following is my current code that doesn't work when I hover over the row.

This is my function that adds a row to the table

```
function addrow()
        {
            var table=document.getElementById("tablelist");
            var row=table.insertRow(-1);
            var cells = new Array();
            for(var i = 0; i < 6;i++)
            {
                cells[i]=row.insertCell(i);
                cells[i].innerHTML="New";
            }
            cells[6]=row.insertCell(6);
            cells[6].innerHTML='<img src="images/pencil-black.png"></img><img src="images/lock-black.png"></img><img src="images/bin-black.png"></img>';
        }
```

jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".userbox td").hover(function() {
var $img = $(this).find("img");
$img.attr("src", $img.attr("src").replace('-black.png', '-white.png'));
}, function() {
    var $img = $(this).find("img");
    $img.attr("src", $img.attr("src").replace('-white.png', '-black.png'));
});  
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When your `document.ready` is running, the elements that are being added by the `addrow()` function do not exist in the DOM yet.

Use jQuery `on`:

```
$(".userbox").on({
    mouseenter: function()  {
         var $img = $(this).find("img");
         $img.attr("src", $img.attr("src").replace('-black.png', '-white.png'));
    },
    mouseleave: function() {
        var $img = $(this).find("img");
        $img.attr("src", $img.attr("src").replace('-white.png', '-black.png'));
    }
}, 'td');
```

Alternatively, you can bind the events when the elements are being created:

```
var tdOnMouseOver = function()
    {
    var $img = $(this).find("img");
    $img.attr("src", $img.attr("src").replace('-black.png', '-white.png'));
    }

var tdOnMouseOut = function()
    {
    var $img = $(this).find("img");
    $img.attr("src", $img.attr("src").replace('-white.png', '-black.png'));
    }

function addrow()
    {
    var table=document.getElementById("tablelist");
    var row=table.insertRow(-1);
    var cells = new Array();

    for(var i = 0; i < 6;i++)
        {
        cells[i]=row.insertCell(i);
        cells[i].innerHTML="New";
        cells[i].onmouseover = tdOnMouseOver;
        cells[i].onmouseout = tdOnMouseOut;
        }

     cells[6]=row.insertCell(6);
     cells[6].innerHTML='<img src="images/pencil-black.png"></img><img src="images/lock-black.png"></img><img src="images/bin-black.png"></img>';
    }
```

**UPDATE (since you're using jQuery 1.6):**

Use jQuery `live`:

```
$(".userbox td").live({
    mouseenter: function()  {
         var $img = $(this).find("img");
         $img.attr("src", $img.attr("src").replace('-black.png', '-white.png'));
    },
    mouseleave: function() {
        var $img = $(this).find("img");
        $img.attr("src", $img.attr("src").replace('-white.png', '-black.png'));
    }
});
```

Comment: I'm getting an error at the `$(".userbox").on({`

Uncaught typeerror: Object[object object] has no method 'on'

Comment: What version of `jQuery` are you using? check using `jQuery.fn.jquery`

Comment: I revised my answer accordingly

Comment: `live()` is deprecated. You should use [`delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) instead

Comment: I'm sorry i have another question. When i hover over the row, the 3 images become the same image but what I'm trying to do is to change all 3 images when i hover over the row.

So any idea what's wrong with it?

Comment: Try: `$(this).find('img').each(function() { $(this).attr('src', $(this).attr('src').replace('-black.png', '-white.png')); } );` and the opposite for the `mouseleave` event.

Answer (score 0):

Use $('#tablelist').on('mouseover mouseout','img',function(e){})

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [delegated events](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events) for events on dynamically added elements:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".userbox").on({
        mouseenter: function() {
            var $img = $(this).find("img");
            $img.attr("src", $img.attr("src").replace('-black.png', '-white.png'));
        }, 
        mouseleave: function() {
            var $img = $(this).find("img");
            $img.attr("src", $img.attr("src").replace('-white.png', '-black.png'));
        }, 'td');
    });
});
```